# How to convert only cells with digits to numeric from character in a dataframe in R and save to an excel file

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I want to convert only the cells that has digits to numeric and save it to an excel file.

For example, The dataframe is similar to this.

`df <- data.frame(row1 = c('agri','1','-', NA),row2 = c('3','import','6', 'food'), stringsAsFactors = F)`

After I save it to an excel file with

`openxlsx::write.xlsx(df, "df.xlsx", row.names=FALSE)`

the digits in the excel file are characters.

[image]

It is because in the dataframe these columns are 'char'.

`> str(df)`

'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:

$ row1: chr  "agri" "1" "-" NA

$ row2: chr  "3" "import" "6" "food"

I tried mutate() and also transform(). But those only works with the entire column.

Is it possible to do it in R?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm unclear about what you're trying to achieve. As you correctly say, the issue is with columns being of type "char". R's `data.frame` does not allow for mixed type entries in one column. Can you include your expected output? For example, you can remove non-numeric entries and store all numeric entries in a `list` via `lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(x[!is.na(as.numeric(x))]))`. Is that what you're after?

Comment: I want an output excel file exactly same as the picture but where only the digits will be numeric and the others will be string as usual. I am not sure whether it is possible to write in excel file like this using R.

Comment: Yes it is possible in R using openxlsx. You just need to fill in each group of values of similar type individually using `uitls::type.convert`

Comment: Thanks dario. Could you please elaborate? I tried `a = df %>% mutate(row1 = ifelse(str_detect(row1, "[1-9]"), utils::type.convert(row1), row1))` and then `write.xlsx` but the digits are still coming as characters (in the picture that I uploaded).

Answer (score 2):

A late comment/response.

**tldr;** I don't think this is possible.

`openxlsx` does allow for cell-level formatting (via `addStyle`), and you could be tempted to use `addStyle` to define different formats for different cells à la

```r
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "sheet1")
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, df)

addStyle(wb, sheet = 1, createStyle(numFmt = "TEXT"), row = 1, col = 1)
addStyle(wb, sheet = 1, createStyle(numFmt = "NUMBER"), row = 3, col = 1)

saveWorkbook(wb, "example.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Inspecting the Excel file reveals that despite the fact that Excel reports cell (row=3, col=1) to have category "Number", the cell is in fact still of category "Text" (as indicated by the little warning triangle).

I can't say whether this is a bug with `openxlsx` or not.

In my personal opinion, this is for the better. Mixing different types of data in one column is bad practice, goes against the fundamentals of R's basic data structures (as entries of elements/columns of a `list`/`data.frame` must all have the same data type), and is the opposite of ["tidy data"](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Comment: While I agree that mixing data types is bad in most cases, we sometimes want to do for aesthetic reasons when reporting outputs. So it would be nice to have this ability.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late response but I was also looking for this. I know exactly what you wanted (We want the numbers in the excel sheets to be numbers, so they can be sorted as numbers, and the text as characters), and there is a way described here [Convert Number Stored as Text in Excel File Using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715415/convert-number-stored-as-text-in-excel-file-using-r)

It is painstakingly slow, and I am looking for a faster way to do it. So, if anyone is more experienced in this, please have a stab.